# Can one have client-side and server-side code invoked from an Asp:RadioButtonList?

Tags: asp.net

I am currently invoking client-side functions and server-side functions from the same button click thus...

```
<asp:Button id="myButton"
            runat="server"
            cssclass="myButtonClass"
            text="Do Stuff"
            onclick="Do_Foo" 
            OnClientClick="Do_Bar();"/>
```

I was wondering if something analagous was possible for a radio button list...

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="myRadioButtonList"
                     runat="server"
                     AutoPostBack="True"
                     onselectedindexchanged="Do_Fum"
                     ...er...something here?>
    <asp:ListItem ...or here perhaps?... Value="0">First Button</asp:ListItem>
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following approach: paste code below in page's `Page_PreRender` event handler

```
foreach (ListItem item in myRadioButtonList.Items)
{
    item.Attributes["onclick"] = "if(!confirm('Are you sure?'))return false";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That did it first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook a change event to radio buttons in javascript like

```
$('#myRadioButtonList').change(function() {
  alert('Handle Your Change');
});
```

Comment: its jquery, just put it in `<script> tag` and make sure add a link to jquery path

Comment: Righto. Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: This script shouldn't work. Change it to this one: `$("#<%= myRadioButtonList.ClientID %> input[type='radio']").change(function () { alert('foo'); });`

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy, @FosterZ, thanks for the suggestions, but all of them result in `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected`.

Comment: Looks like you don't include reference to jQuery library file

Comment: @Yuriy, you are right, I didn't. But when I added it, a lot of gross errors started ocurring in the application. So I'll leave off this line of enquiry. Thank you for trying, anyway.